How to make the wrap text around the image in three columns?
is there an opportunity in latex to make the text flow around the table like in this picture?

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the TeX code you have tried so far!

You could use flowfram, but you will need set up the page in the preamble, and manually break paragraphs.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694308/two-figure-wrapping-issue/694314?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C0.0000#694314 on the use of \splitpar and \continuepar.

You have to give tex a bit if help, but for a hand written document it is not usually hard to add the markup at the right places to fit with the natural column breaks.

\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\def\tttta{One two three four five six seven eight \stepcounter{enumi}\roman{enumi} nine ten.}
\def\ttttb{Red green blue. \tttta\ \tttta\ \tttta\ \tttta\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}

  \ttttb\ttttb

  \tttta\ This that the other.  This that the other.

  \newcolumn

  \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{.5\columnwidth}
    \makebox[\linewidth][l]{\parbox[t]{.5\textwidth}{%
        \centering
    \caption{ffff}
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image}
    }}
    \end{wrapfigure}


  \ttttb
  
  \tttta

  \tttta\  This that the other.  This that the other.


  \newcolumn

  \vspace*{10\baselineskip}
  
  \ttttb\ttttb
\end{multicols}
\end{document}


See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530084/i-want-to-wrap-text-only-above-and-below-a-figure-inside-of-a-column
